# Weak object in an NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

I would like to store a zeroing weak reference to an object in a `NSDictionary`. This is for a reference to a parent `NSDictionary`, so I can crawl back up a large structure without searching.

I can not use `__weak` here; even if my local reference is weak, the `NSDictionary` will store a strong reference to the object that was weakly referenced. And, of course, `NSDictionary` can't have `nil` objects.

I'm on iOS, not Mac, so `NSHashTable` isn't available. And I only want one object to be weak; the rest should still be strong.

(I'm going to post my answer, so I have something to mark as accepted if there's no better answer. But I'm hoping someone has a better answer.)

Comment: I created [this](https://gist.github.com/firelizzard18/6326536) to be a dictionary that stores objects as effectively zeroing weak references. It could be modified (and cleaned up) to serve your purposes.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In iOS 6+ you can use [NSMapTable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMapTable_class/Reference/NSMapTable.html) and choose if you want objects and/or keys to be weak or strong.

Comment: Clearly the best answer for today and forward. Thanks.

Comment: NSMapTable might not behave as expected: http://cocoamine.net/blog/2013/12/13/nsmaptable-and-zeroing-weak-references/

Comment: NSMapTable will do the job. But still curious about how `valueWithNonretainedObject` works? It holds a `__weak` reference or `__unsafe_unretained ` one. @Timo say [it works like `__unsafe_unretained `](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18080450/531966). Is that correct?

Comment: That is easy to test. Make an autorelease pool. Set the value of the key to your object. "destroy" your object. Then after the autorelease pool check the value of the key

Comment: @Nickolas nsmaptable doesn't support the options you ask!

Answer (score 15):

I've settled on defining a "container" class with a single member, like this:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id parent;
@end

@implementation Parent

@synthesize parent = _parent;

- (id)initWithParent: (id)parent;
{
    if (( self = [super init] )) {
        _parent = parent;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

And using it:

```
id parentRef = [[Parent alloc] initWithParent: parent];
[newElement setObject: parentRef forKey: ParentKey];
```

I think this will work for me, but it seems **crazy** that there's no better way built in to Foundation.

Comment: Sounds like the only solution to me - that's how I would have done it as well. Or an `NSValue` but that wouldn't zero out.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I also thought about a container, I still didn't tried but I'm trying to make make something close to what you do with block `id __weak weakObject=strongObject; [optionDict setValue:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:tmpObject] forKey:key]; ` still need to figure out if it works.

Comment: Old comment, but I'll add this one for new visitors. What Andrea says won't work, the dictionary would retain the object anyway.

Answer (score 7):

There is a built-in way; just use:

```
[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:object]];
```

Then to access the object later, use:

```
id object = [[array objectAtIndex:i] nonretainedObjectValue];
```

If the value has been released since you added it then "object" will be an invalid pointer under iOS 4.x, and (I'm assuming) will be nil under 5.x with ARC enabled.

EDIT: my assumption was wrong - it's not weak under ARC (see discussion below).

Comment: The dangling pointer should never be accessed, though, as your object is close-to-death at that moment. So accessing the parent here should be a bug anyway, which in this case isn't hidden by niling out.

Comment: @Eiko, you're wrong. It's a common case for observer pattern.