# NSNotificationCenter : list of observers?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

Is it possible to get the list of observers (objects and selectors) for a given notification name? (NSNotificationCenter)

Comment: Please try solution by 0xced (<http://stackoverflow.com/users/21698/0xced>) "<http://stackoverflow.com/a/13274854/505735>"

Comment: This should help you out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346700/nsnotificationcenter-list-of-observers/34692724#34692724

Answer (score 30, accepted):

(iOS 9, Swift 3) If you want to find out which observers are currently registered in `NotificationCenter`, break and print its debug description:

```
(lldb) e print(NotificationCenter.default.debugDescription)
```

Each line of the output will contain *(Notification) Name*, *Object*, *Observer*, *Options*. Multiple calls to `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` with some `NSNotification.Name` will result in multiple entries in this list.

---

NB. while this might prove useful information when debugging, I would not advise to manage observers at runtime using this output.

---

(source: [answer](http://paul-van-klaveren.github.io/2017/list-notificationcenter-observers/) based on [useyourloaf](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/unregistering-nsnotificationcenter-observers-in-ios-9/))

Comment: `(lldb) e [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter].debugDescription` works for obj-c.

Answer (score 16):

I don't think there is an (official) way of retrieving the list of observers for a given notification name from `NSNotificationCenter`. However, you could create a subclass of `NSNotificationCenter` and then override the following methods:

- `+ defaultCenter`
- `- addObserver:selector:name:object`
- `- addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:`
- `- removeObserver:`
- `- removeObserver:name:object`

In the overriding implementations of the instance methods, you would then keep track of the observers for a given notification name using a dictionary. In each overridden instance method you would finally call `NSNotificationCenter`'s respective `super` method. Additionally, you would provide a method to retrieve your own list of observers for the given name, for example:

```
- (id)observerForNotificationName:(NSString *)name
```

However, there are two issues with this approach: first, `NSMutableDictionary` would retain all observers in a naive implementation, which is probably not the same behavior `NSNotificationCenter` implements. Second, you would have to change the code that gets the default notification center by `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` (or any other `NSNotificationCenter` instance) so as to use your custom subclass.

Note that the first issue is solvable using a `CFDictionary` with weak reference callbacks, a [container class with a weak reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748736/weak-object-in-an-nsdictionary) to the respective observer, or, if you are in a garbage collected environment on Mac OS X, an `NSHashTable`.

Comment: `NSHashTable` is (very unfortunately) only useful if you're using Garbage Collection.

Answer (score 5):

There is no public API to query `NSNotificationCenter` about the list of current observers for any object or notification.

The previous answer outlines a solution and goes to some level of detail regarding the ownership of observers, in a subclass of `NSNotificationCenter` designed to collect and provide such information.

However, this solution can only be used with your own code, that will call the subclass of `NSNotiicationCenter`. What about other code, both in the system and external libraries who use the base `NSNotificationCenter` for registering/unregistering for notifications?

I suggest instead of subclassing `NSNotificationCenter`, using a bit of low-level ObjC to swizzle the method implementations of original `NSNotifictionCenter`, replacing them with our own implementations, that will work more-or-less as described in the previous answer, and will call the original implementations as their last act.

Here's how to do this: http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/

Then, you can be sure you get ALL the observers of some notification, and that your code is portable and usable with 3rd party code that directly uses `NSNotificationCenter`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using NSNotificationCenter, you can try this [ObserversCenter](https://github.com/yonglam/ObserversCenter). And you can get the list of observers.

About ObserverCenter:

1. it implements an multi-observer pattern as NSNotificationCenter;
2. it decouple the observed and observers, so they don't know each other;
3. you can subscribe on a specified key;
4. you can call the real interface when making a notification.

Comment: NSNotificationCenter is also cross-app (process) and has many system-wide behaviors that any 3rd party mechanism cannot  imitate. You cannot observe Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch standard notification (e.g. appWillbecomeForeground etc.) using a 3rd party mechanism. So - the preferable way is to extend the existing one with care.

Answer (score 1):

I created a category on NSNotificationCenter and swizzled the addObserver:::: method.

This is only for debugging and should never be in production code as it will lead to retain cycles

```
@interface NSNotificationCenter (Tracking)
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray <NSDictionary *> * observers;
@end


#import <JRSwizzle/JRSwizzle.h>
@implementation NSNotificationCenter (Tracking)

+ (void)initialize {
    [super initialize];
    [self jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(addObserver:selector:name:object:)
                withMethod:@selector(SNaddObserver:selector:name:object:)
                     error:nil];
}

- (void)SNaddObserver:(id)observer selector:(SEL)aSelector name:(NSString *)aName object:(id)anObject {
    NSDictionary *obs = @{@"observer"   :observer,
                          @"selector"   :NSStringFromSelector(aSelector),
                          @"name"       :aName
                          };
    DDLogDebug(@"observer added : %@", obs);
    [[self observers] addObject:obs];
    [self SNaddObserver:observer selector:aSelector name:aName object:anObject];
}

- (NSMutableArray <NSDictionary *> *) observers{
    static NSMutableArray <NSDictionary *> * _observers = nil;
    if (!_observers) {
        _observers = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return _observers;
}

@end
```

Comment: with some enhancement, that could become a viable solution. 1) use some CF collection that allows for weak references instead of your NSDictionary - so to not create more references to the observing objects. 2) make your SNAddObserver thread-safe (use dispatch_once for creating your collections) 3) cleanup from time to time, as observers are removed.

Comment: @MottiShneor I've been looking for something similar to that weak reference cf collection. Is that really possible possible though? Any resources would be great

Comment: @pnizzle give NSMapTable a try? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmaptable

Comment: Yes, NSMapTable is a more modern solution to this problem and probably more well suited, as it won't retain the observers

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @PDK's answer, `po NotificationCenter.default` (or the appropriate instance) will yield debug information:

```
<NSNotificationCenter:0x600000f84310>
Name, Object, Observer, Options
UIApplicationSimpleRemoteActionNotification, 0x7faac90069a0, 0x600000f84fc0, 1400
NSTextStorageDidProcessEditingNotification, 0x7faacd80d080, 0x600001808a00, 1400
com.apple.ManagedConfiguration.profileListChanged, 0x600000b0e280, 0x600000b0e280, 1400
UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, 0x7faac90069a0, 0x600000ff75d0, 1400
UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, 0x7faac90069a0, 0x600001880d00, 1400
```

This works on Xcode 12, on older versions, the `debugDescription` may be necessary.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the `observationInfo` property of NSObject?

```
observationInfo
Returns a pointer that identifies information about all of the observers that are registered with the receiver.
```

Comment: That's for key/value observing, I think, not NSNotificationCenter observers.

Comment: You could be right. I haven't tried it with NSNotificationCenter