# How to retrieve all NSNotificationCenter observers?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

I'd like to retrieve a list of observers (objects and selectors) for a given notification name. I know there's no official API for that. I also know I could [subclass NSNotificationCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10346700/235297) to accomplish this. Sometimes however this is not a viable option because NSNotificationCenter usage is spread all over the code or even binary frameworks.

So I'm looking for an unofficial/private way to do this. (Since it's about debugging only, that's fine.)

Comment: You may just want to swizzle the methods so you get the object: http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling

Comment: here is an answer which implements swizzling to track observers

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346700/nsnotificationcenter-list-of-observers/34692724#34692724

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally, Apple added a way to print all notification center observers:

```
po [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
```

It prints a comma separated list with Name, Object, Observer, and Options:

```
<NSNotificationCenter:0x7f997b307500>
Name, Object, Observer, Options
WebPreferencesRemovedNotification, 0x11165b680, 0x116c87ff8, 1400
UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, 0x11165b680, 0x7f997a838000, 1400
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to subclass `NSNotificationCenter` you can rename original `addObserver:selector:name:object` method and create your own with such name and add observers in there to some array then call original renamed method.

Take a look at following methods: `class_addMethod`, `class_replaceMethod`, `class_getMethodImplementation`.

Also look at this SO question: [Method Swizzling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267506/how-to-swizzle-a-class-method-on-ios)

I am not sure why you want observers but you might find this class useful, which removes observers automatically for you which I think might be what you want. [SFObservers](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/SFObservers)

Comment: +1 for `SFObservers`! The SO question you're pointing to is actually from me (including the solution) ;-)

Comment: Hahah, nice solution & question though:D

Comment: here is an answer which implements swizzling to track observers

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346700/nsnotificationcenter-list-of-observers/34692724#34692724