# Disable all notification observers in a certain viewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, swift4

I used `NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` in many places in my app. but I want to disable all of them in just a ViewController for example named `vc`. in vc I called `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` in `viewWillDisappear` method. but when I opened a URL in Safari and use the back-to-app button to come back to my app all the notifications were triggered again.
is there a way to disable all of the notifications in my whole application and enable them again?

Comment: Grab all notifications which you want to disable using subclassing. Have a look here. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/10346882/2545465