# iOS - Posting notification called twice

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, observers

I add an observer in a function which I call on the start. It is only initiated once(I thoroughly checked). On the safer side, I also remove observers before I add observers. below is the function

```
func setupLiveCycleNotifications() {
       
       SweeprClient.removeNotificationObservers()

       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                   selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground),
                   name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                   selector: #selector(appMovedToForeground),
                   name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }
```

In my UNIT TEST functions, I tried to test this feature. I initiate the class and I post the notifications like shown below:

```
let backgroundExpectation = self.expectation(description: "background expectation")
let foregroundExpectation = self.expectation(description: "foreground expectation")
Client.modules!.subscribe(module: "session", event: SessionProvider .Events.application_lifecycle.rawValue,
                                tag: nil) { result, tag in
    if result == "background" {
        backgroundExpectation.fulfill()
    }

    if result == "foreground" {
        foregroundExpectation.fulfill()
    }

}
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
wait(for: [backgroundExpectation], timeout: Config.Timeout)
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
wait(for: [foregroundExpectation], timeout: Config.Timeout)
```

The feature is to call back to my modules where I fulfill the expectation but, the problem is both background and foreground are called TWICE. I don't know why. I reset multiple times.I removed observers in many places but, nothing works. Even if I comment the posting of notifications.Nobody calls my module. So, I am sure I am the only one who calls these notifications.

- I removed observers in multiple places
- I commented out the post notifications but the expectation only gets timed out, Nobody calls it

Comment: `SweeprClient.removeNotificationObservers()`: What's that method doing? Because you are removing on a class method? But you add `self` for the observers?

Comment: I didn't test if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346700/nsnotificationcenter-list-of-observers can list double listed, but might worth a look

Comment: sorry the remove observers is a private helper function which calls the remove observer like :  NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

Comment: Does it fails only in UnitTest? If yes, maybe check the `setUp()`/`tearDown()` methods?

Comment: yeah the weird thing it fails only if I run the entire test suite like about 50 test together. If I run it individually, it works fine. My only doubt was may be some other leftover is posting but if I comment out the posting in my function, nobody calls it the observer. So, I am sure there is no left over from previous tests. I don't have any setup and tear down by the way

Comment: And there is only one test method that register? If not, use the teardown, or maybe just disabling the parallels tests might work, but tearDown should be better. In it, just call removeObserver methods.

Comment: I actually call the remove observer in the function itself before I post the notification

Comment: Is there any async call in your test suite?

Comment: no there is no async call