# Need assistance regarding memory management

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

**vc2.h**

```
@interface vc2 : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *dict;

@end
```

**vc2.m**

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.dict = @{@"self":self};
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Root VC**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    vc = [[vc2 alloc]init];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    vc = nil;
}
```

`vc2` strong `NSDictionary` property holds `self` and I am setting `vc2` to `nil` in root VC but when I check this in instruments `vc2` instance still exists.

When I set `weak` `NSDictionary` property `vc2` instance gets released after setting it to `nil`, but Xcode gives me this warning *Assigning dictionary literal to a weak property; object will be released after assignment*

What is going on regarding this memory management?

Comment: Try put a weak self into the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if the reference to dictionary is `strong`, `vc2` creates a retain cycle - it references itself through the dictionary. So dropping the reference to it from root won't help, there will still be at least one reference existing - the one from dictionary.

It's simple - if there is a reference to an object, it has to be retained, you cannot release it. Since `vc2` holds a reference to the dictionary, the dictionary cannot be released while `vc2` exists. However, the dictionary itself holds a reference to `vc2`, therefore `vc2` cannot be released until the dictionary exists. This is the retain cycle - **`vc2` keeps the dictionary alive, and the dictionary keeps the `vc2` alive**.

You can break this cycle by using `weak` reference type - weak means that this reference will not be used to determine if the object has to be retained. From the viewpoint of retaining/releasing the `weak` references don't count. So when you make the dictionary property `weak`, you are saying that the `vc2` should not keep the dictionary alive. In other words, you are saying that if no other object has a reference to this dictionary, `vc2` should not be a reason for retaining it and in such a case the dictionary can be released. BUT, since when you create the dictionary in `vc2` the ONLY reference to it is the one in `vc2`, the `weak` one, there is no `strong` reference to it that would prevent releasing it. This results in following:

```
// here you create a dictionary and assign it to your weak dict property
self.dict = @{@"self":self};
// but right here, after executing it, the only reference to the created dictionary
// is the weak one - that means that the dictionary can be released!
// thus, if you try to print dict right on the next line, it will be nil
// because it was released right after creation
```

That's the problem with using `weak` reference to the dictionary. Every object is retained (exists) only when there is at least one `strong` reference to it. But in this case the poor dictionary will not get a single `strong` reference to it.

What you want here is a `strong` reference to a dictionary. That will make sure that the dictionary will exist while the `vc2` exists. But you need to break the retain cycle somewhere. To identify what is supposed to be `weak` is pretty easy: just ask which object is supposed to be dependent on which:

- *Can the dictionary be released, while the `vc2` exists?*
- No, it cannot, dictionary should be retained while the `vc2` exists.
- *Can the `vc2` be released, while the dictionary exists?*
- Yes it can! In fact, when `vc2` is released, that's the point when dictionary can be released too.

This means that the dictionary is dependent on the `vc2`, not vice versa. So you want a strong reference from `vc2` to dictionary - that will make sure that while `vc2` exists, the dictionary exists. But you don't want the existence of the dictionary to keep the `vc2` retained - when other objects release `vc2`, the dictionary must not hold the `vc2` alive. Therefore you need a `weak` reference from the dictionary to the `vc2`, not a `strong` one. That should point you in the right direction - the `self` reference that you are adding to the dictionary is the one that should be `weak`.

Check for example this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748736/weak-object-in-an-nsdictionary) for some advices on how to approach weak entries in a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for replying can you please tell in bit detail why setting vc to nil will not clear self in dict, dict object is in vc and when the whole class is set to nil why it wont work on dict holding self, is the self in dict is another copy?

Comment: @Pursuingperfection I tried to elaborate on the explanation.. `self` in `dict` is basically another reference to the `vc2`, so if it is `strong`, it will keep the `vc2` around..

Comment: @Pursuingperfection glad to help