# ARC weak and strong references with outlets and collection of outlets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, outlet

I would have more information about *ARC* and weak and strong reference :

Actually, if I have :

```
@interface
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIButton * button
@property (weak) UIView *subview
@end

@implementation

-(BOOL) viewDidLoad
{
    UIView *aSubView= [[UIView alloc]....];
    [self.view addSubview:aSubview];
    self.subview = aSubview;
}
```

It's normal to have weak reference for the button because its superview have a strong reference on it.

Now, I add `UIView` programmatically, I also put a weak reference because when I will add this subView in a superview, there will be a strong reference. First question : Is this a good method ?

Now my real problems are on the second source code with the collection. What can I put with `IBOutletCollection`?

And if I want to keep an array of views which are added programmatically I can't because `NSArray` keep strong reference and views' superview too so there will be some leaks . How can I have a `NSArray` of my subviews without leaks ?

```
@property (?) IBOutletCollection .....
@property (?) NSArray *subviews

-(BOOL) viewDidLoad
{
    ?
}
```

Comment: You should look up what an ARC circular reference is to help you understand this. You can have as many strong references as you want as long as you don't create a circular reference (also called "retain cycle").  So it's fine for your properties to be `strong` instead of `weak`; in fact, this is common if you might be removing a subview from one place and adding it to another superview later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlets are usually weak references because the views are owned by their superviews. If you make them a weak reference, all you have to do to get rid of a view object is remove it from it's superview, and the outlet gets zeroed out.

Your example of a subview that you create programmatically is the same thing, and making it weak is a good idea.

Your NSArray of subviews needs to be a strong reference or the array will be released. Same goes with an IBOutletCollection, which is really just an array maintained by the system.

You will need to remove your views from these arrays yourself if you want them to be released prior to the owning view controller being released.

You could probably create your own equivalent of an outlet collection using an NSPointerArray, which does not retain the pointers that you pass to it. However, you would need to be careful because it also does not zero out items that are released, so you would get zombies if you removed items from your view but did not remove their entry in the NSPointerArray.

All things considered, I would suggest just using a regular mutable array and doing your own housekeeping on the contents to remove items from the array if you remove them from their superview.

Comment: So I have to  clearObject from my NSArray, but where do I have to do that, didReceiveMemoryWarning and viewDidDisappear ?

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, yes that is the recommended strategy for subview properties. As to the second question, I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. [Here's a good tutorial on IBOutletCollection](http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/) if that's what you're looking for. If not, please clarify what you're problem with IBOutletCollection is.

Answer (score 0):

1) When you add a subview programatically, you can keep a weak reference as a property in your view controller.

2) IBOutletCollection is actually removed by the preprocessor and doesn't mean anything to the compiler. It's just a hint within XCode that there's an outlet collection associated with the property.

3) Here's a page that talks about using NSArray to store weak references:

[NSArray of weak references (__unsafe_unretained) to objects under ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336288/nsarray-of-weak-references-to-objects-under-arc)