# NSArray in Objective C - what does it contain

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I have such code:

```
Fruit *fruit= [[Fruit alloc] init];

// This is effectively two different things right, one is "fruit" - the pointer, and another thing is the object it is pointing to (the one that was allocated using alloc/init) - though not directly visible
```

When I add this to `NSArray`:

```
[myArray addObject: fruit];
```

What gets added to the array is *actually a pointer* to the Fruit class object, right?

Comment: In objective c, you don't have addObject method for NSArray. Unless you can use NSMutableArray for addObject method. Yes, if you use addObject Fruit to NSMutableArray, it contains the pointer that links the object Fruit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a *copy* of the *pointer*, which points to a valid initialized object, so the following won't cause an issue (under ARC, at least):

```
Fruit *fruit= [[Fruit alloc] init];
[myArray addObject: fruit];
fruit = nil;     // OK, array still contains a valid Fruit object
```

Comment: I have a question regardless this topic what's happened when you do [myArray addObject:&fruit]; ? Do you add a week pointer?

Comment: @trojanfoe: ok, maybe stupid question: but why have this pointers at all like here in obj c? why not have for example all objects put on stack or somewhere else :)

Comment: @Greg you may wanna read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336288/nsarray-of-weak-references-to-objects-under-arc

Comment: @user2568508 They are pointers to dynamically allocated memory on "the heap".  Stack size is limited and the stack changes as functions are called, etc., so it's no the place to store objects that you want to persist throughout the process's lifetime.

Comment: @trojanfoe: ok ........ So NSArray basically stores pointers to the objects, not the objects themselves ...

Comment: @user2568508 Yes, however it's common to talk about a pointer-to-object as being "the object".

Comment: @trojanfoe: Yep I encountered this, although it is a bit confusing....  one may agree :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it adds a strong pointer to your object.

Using ARC remember that an object is automatically dealloc'd when there are no strong pointers to them. This means that by design if you use ARC you need to set any pointer to an object that you have to "nil" in order to deallocate it. This includes for instance a pointer stored in an NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

As you know if *var is the value at the pointer then `var` is pointer (as in c language)

which means if *fruit  is the object then you are adding the pointer `fruit` to the array like `[myArray addObject: fruit];`