# Sort NSDictionary By property of object stored as value

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am storing data in `NSMutableDictionary` To store data received by web service.

I want to display data in alpha order but as we know Dictionary store data in their own way so I m getting different order for iOS 5 and iOS 6. iOS 5 it is fine but in iOS 6 it change order.

I am storing int key and object as value.

object contain ID,Name and Description.

```
EX:
  key  value
  1 -  (12,bhgjksd,kijdh)
  6 -  (13,kjfd,ikjk)
  2 -  (14,ljiuhbdf,dsjhfj)
```

How can I sort my Dictionary by Object.Name property.
or get key based on Object.Name sorting order.

I don't want to sort on key I want to sort on Object.Name which is stored in value part as object.

Any kind of help is welcome.....
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can have a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118932/how-can-i-sort-nsmutabledictionary-with-keys-value

Comment: hi Amrit thanks to have time. But in that question he want sorting based on key while i want sorting based on value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

     return (NSComparisonResult)[obj1.name compare:obj2.name];;
}];
```

You will get all the keys in `sortedKeys` array, sorted in the order of `object.name` property. You can use these keys to get the values from dictionary as `[dict valueForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:i]]`. For more details please [check apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:).

Comment: thanks This solved my problem I fond it from keysSortedByValueUsingComparator. First I found it from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217421/sort-nsdictionary-keys-by-dictionary-value-into-an-nsarray?rq=1. Thanks to try help me.

Comment: This also help me to campare NSString http://getsetgames.com/2009/12/10/iphonedev-advent-tip-10-string-comparison-using-nsstring/

Comment: I was not aware that I can accept only one answer SO i go for select another answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Object.Name" ascending:YES];
[items sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

Also,

```
NSArray *ordered = [myDictionary keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
    return [obj1.name compare:obj2.name];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks to try help me. I solved my problem by keysSortedByValueUsingComparator

Comment: This also help me to campare NSString http://getsetgames.com/2009/12/10/iphonedev-advent-tip-10-string-comparison-using-nsstring/

Comment: I did not copy from you, I just posted answer in 2-ways. And its upto the OP, which way he wants. Even there is some differences in your and my answer. I dont care if someone accepts my answer or not. Even a downvote will be fine for me ;)