# How to sort this case?

Tags: ios, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

How to sort this kind of case?

1. I have a `NSMutableArray`.
2. My `NSMutableArray` can have an object or `NSMutableDictionary`.
3. My `NSMutableDictionary` only has 1 object (an object as its object and a string as its key)
4. Both object is the same and has attribute `name`

Now, what I'm struggle with is I want to sort the `NSMutableArray` based on the dictionary key and the object's `name`? (let's just ignore the object that is added to `NSMutableArray`)

Bunch of thanks to person can give me idea how to solve this case!

Comment: It will be really helpful if you could give some example of what you are trying to do. Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738082/sort-nsdictionary-by-property-of-object-stored-as-value/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your `NSMutableArray` to a custom subclass of NSObject and sort using a custom NSComparator, like so:

```
(NSComparator)^(id obj1, id obj2){ /* obj1 and obj2 are NSMutableArrays */
      if ([obj1 objectAtIndex:1] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]) {
           // sort according to the dictionary case
      } else { // [obj1 objectAtIndex:1] isKindOfClass:[NSObject class]
           // sort according to the your other, default case
      }
}
```

Do note that this is untested and that you'll need to fill in the bodies of the if and else statements. The comment by the else clause is just how I code and you can eliminate it if it doesn't conform to your taste.