# NSSet: return an NSArray of objects sorted by a list of strings on certain property of each object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsset

I have an `NSSet` of objects.

Each object in the set is an instance of `MyObject` with a property called `name`.

I have another `NSArray` called nameIndexes which contains name values.

I would like to have a function that takes the `NSSet` and returns a sorted array sorted using the name property based on its position in the nameIndexes array.

**Edit:**

Sorry for my misleading, here is an example:

I have a set of MyObject(may not be in the same order):

```
MyObject1 {name:@"A"}

MyObject2 {name:@"B"}

MyObject3 {name:@"C"}
```

I have another array of names:

```
{"B", "A", "C"}
```

I want an NSArray of:

```
{MyObject2, MyObject1, MyObject3}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Erm... @robhasacamera, your edit has changed the question.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes it did. It might have been what hzxu was asking, but he cannot be sure.  I rolled it back to the original version (which still doesn't really make sense).

Comment: Yes, but you changed the fact that he had an additional array that he wanted to use to sort the set.

Comment: @Fogmeister Ah, I misread part of it. My mistake. Was trying to help clarify it as I saw multiple comments where people were not 100% sure was what being asked. Guess I was a little confused too.

Comment: @hzxu, Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738082/sort-nsdictionary-by-property-of-object-stored-as-value

Comment: @ACB Hi it is not what I am looking for, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @hzxu, That was just to point you in right direction. Did any of the below answers help you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSSet *set = //your set.

NSArray *nameIndexes = //the array of names for sorting.

NSArray *result = [[set allObjects] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(MyObject *obj1, MyObject *obj2) {
    int index1 = [nameIndexes indexOfObject:obj1.name];
    int index2 = [nameIndexes indexOfObject:obj2.name];
    return [[NSNumber numberWithInt:index1] compare:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index2]];
}];
```

Not 100% certain what you are asking but this will sort take the set of names and turn it into a sorted array sorted based on the index of the names in a second array.

**After edit**

Edit... ok, so your edit completely changed the question.  Anyway, from the edit you can just do...

```
NSArray *result = [[set allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:"name" ascending:YES]]];
```

This will take the set and return a sorted array sorted by the name property of the objects in alphabetical order.

Comment: Hi I've updated my question with an example, can you have a look?

Comment: My first example will do this for you.

Comment: +1: That was edited so many times that you did a very good job understanding the question.