# How to maintain an internal array of instances of a class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, static, instances

I'm trying to maintain an *internal* array of all the instances of a given class. When one is naturally dealloc'd it should be removed from that static array.

However, `dealloc` will never get called if `[instances addObject:weakSelf]` is uncommented. When that is commented out, then `dealloc` messages appear normally. How can this be achieved?

```
__weak MyClass *weakSelf;    // A weak reference to myself
static NSMutableArray *instances;

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (!instances) {
            instances = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }
        weakSelf = self;

        // Remember this instance
        [instances addObject:weakSelf];
        NSLog(@"Instances count: %lu", (unsigned long)instances.count);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // Remove this instance from the array
    [instances removeObject:weakSelf];
    NSLog(@"Instances count now: %lu", (unsigned long)instances.count);
}

+ (void)doSomething {
    // enumerate the instances array and perform some action on each
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a `NSValue` nonretain:

```
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:self];
[instances addObject:value];
```

Ref: [NSArray of weak references (__unsafe_unretained) to objects under ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336288/nsarray-of-weak-references-unsafe-unretained-to-objects-under-arc)

Or using "a category that makes NSMutableArray optionally store weak references"

```
@implementation NSMutableArray (WeakReferences)
    + (id)mutableArrayUsingWeakReferences {
    return [self mutableArrayUsingWeakReferencesWithCapacity:0];
    }

    + (id)mutableArrayUsingWeakReferencesWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)capacity {
    CFArrayCallBacks callbacks = {0, NULL, NULL, CFCopyDescription, CFEqual};
    // We create a weak reference array
    return (id)(CFArrayCreateMutable(0, capacity, &callbacks));
    }
@end
```

Ref: [Non-retaining array for delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692161/non-retaining-array-for-delegates/4692229#4692229)

Comment: Your ref lead me in the right direction (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4692229/4755085), so I ended up making a category on NSMutableArray that works well. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use NSPointerArray?